# How to include multiple stylesheets and js files in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0

I have included a stylesheet in Magento2 through `default_head_blocks.xml` but now I am trying to include multiple `css` and `js` files by the same mechanism but its not happening.

Comment: what did you tried so far can you share that code?

Answer (score 1):

you can add as many

```
    <head>
            <css src="css/style.css" />  // for css 
            <link src="js/functions.js"/> //for js 
    </head>
```

after adding the `css` and `js` remove folder `view_preprocessed`  then run this command from cli  `bin/php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Answer (score 0):

Its not helping.
My code

```
<head>
        <meta name="x_ua_compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <css src="mage/calendar.css"/>
        <css src="css/customstyle2.css" />
        <css src="css/customstyle.css" />
        <link src="requirejs/require.js"/>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are running in developer mode

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

or run the deploy command `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`